# How can I use a prepared statement when using the built-in YEAR function in Derby?

Tags: java, sql, derby

This is for a homework assignment using Java and Derby.

The below compiles and runs fine, though my compiler isn't happy about it.

```
String getTotalWeightFromSingleYear = "SELECT SUM(weight) as total_weight From Hive where YEAR(harvestdate) = ? ORDER BY total_weight";
            PreparedStatement psGetTotalWeightFromSingleYear = connection.prepareStatement(getTotalWeightFromSingleYear);
            psGetTotalWeightFromSingleYear.setInt(1, rs.getInt("just_year"));
            resultSet = psGetTotalWeightFromSingleYear.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
```

The IDE reports that it cannot resolve parameter query 1 and I think it is preventing the ORDER BY portion of the query from running. Can I use a prepared statement when using the built-in YEAR function? If so, how.

Comment: Hi, can you please paste the exact error you get?

Comment: Also, pick one option between "The below compiles and runs fine" and "my compiler isn't happy about it". They're mutually exclusive.

Comment: The error is in the post "Cannot resolve query parameter '1'". The code compiles, but the results aren't sorted. The IDE (IntelliJ) reports an error, but still compiles. I'd post a screenshot, but don't have the rep yet.

Comment: I don't even understand how this query could return more than 1 result: there is no `group by` clause. And if the query returns a single result, the `order by` clause is useless.